# Sharepoint 2013 - Home Owners Permissions Group Shows Site Appearance Differently Than Other Groups

Tags: css, sharepoint

SharePoint 2013 Teamsite with publishing feature enabled.

We (Home Owners/Admins) made some custom branding changes via css, and enabled the logo on each subsite to link back to the parent/main site home page.  These aren't visible/functioning when when someone who isn't in the Home Owner group is viewing the site.  Don't get it!

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply published my masterpage and all users saw changes!  I am a numnuts, sorry!